# How to add an extra page to abstract in Cambridge University thesis template?

Tags: abstract

I want to add an extra page   to abstract  in Cambridge University  thesis template.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can have as many pages as you want, you can also have multiple abstracts. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course, only if you are talking about https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template You haven't specified anything.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?